# WCF enqueued requests

Tags: wcf, azure, queue, azure-worker-roles

In our application we have a WCF "standalone" published on a Azure WorkerRole (Cloud Service). In this WCF, we have modified the throttling and limited the maximum number of concurrent calls. When this value is exceeded, the WCF queued requests. We don't know where are queued.
For the application's features the requests can't be enqueued or enqueued less time as soon as possible.

We can see these queues?
How can we change the parameters to not enqueued?

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot of.

Comment: We are using WCF BasicHttpBinding.

Comment: Maybe setting the timeout to something low will prevent stuff from being queued up

Answer (score 0):

I modify all the timeouts there are in the HHTP binding:
   binding.ReceiveTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
   binding.OpenTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
   binding.CloseTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
   binding.SendTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)

I have put all timeouts to 1 second. But the behavior is the same. The requests are queued.
The changes we have made have been in the Server binding.